# In Excel, how I can find working day from hours?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an input column like this:

```
Q3 column
34:48:00
34:18:00
10:51:00
48:14:00
9:40:00
15:01:00
5:19:00
18:33:00
```

"calculations for just first row of this column=34:48/8:30"

I want my output like this:

```
Days
4.05
and others
```

How could I do this?

I've tried this using `=INT(Q3/"8:30")` but this is giving me only integer number!

My working hours in a day is 8:30.

Comment: Excel times are actually floating-point numbers where a day is 1 and hours/minutes/seconds are fractions of a day.  It's only when you set the formatting that this numbering is discombobulated.  So, knowing this, it's possible to convert from, eg, hours/minutes to fractional hours or fractional days -- simple matter of arithmetic.  In particular, if you have accumulated hours/minutes, simply display the sum as a floating point number to get 24-hour days/fractions.  To get 8:30 hour days, divide by 8.5.

Comment: could you plz calculate  34hr 48 min  /  8 hr 30 min  ?

Comment: I got it slightly wrong above -- `=(cell * 24 / 8.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `=Q3/"8:30"`?  Did you get `97:24:42`?  If so, you’re 99% of the way home. 
That (`97:24:42`) is your answer, expressed as a number of days
(4 days is 96 hours; and 0.05882 days is 1 hour, 24 minutes, and 42 seconds). 
All you need to do now is Format the cell as a Number, as follows:

- Click on the cell.
- Either

  - type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>),
    or,
  - on the “Home” tab, in the “Cells” panel, click on the “Format” button and select “Format Cells…” from the drop-down menu.
- Then, in the “Number” tab (which will be selected initially by default), click on either “General” or “Number” -- the “Sample” field will show what it will look like.
- And then click on “OK”.

Comment: your answer is correct but how i can convert 97:24:42 to 4.05??

Comment: I updated the answer.